# error LNK2005 already defined in card.obj

Tags: c, visual-studio

this code gives me error LNK2005 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 getCardHolderName already defined in card.obj and
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Payment_Application
what should I do ??

```
  //main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "STD_TYPES.h"
#include "card.c"

ST_cardData_t NewCustomer;

void main(void)
{
    uint8_t x;
    x=getCardHolderName(NewCustomer.cardHolderName);
    if (x == 0)
    {
        printf("Name is Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Name is Invalid");
    }
}

//card.h
#ifndef _CARD_H
#define _CARD_H

#include "STD_TYPES.h"

typedef struct ST_cardData_t
{
    uint8_t cardHolderName[25];
    uint8_t primaryAccountNumber[20];
    uint8_t cardExpirationDate[6];
}ST_cardData_t;


typedef enum EN_cardError_t
{
    OK, WRONG_NAME, WRONG_EXP_DATE, WRONG_PAN
}EN_cardError_t;

EN_cardError_t getCardHolderName(ST_cardData_t* cardData);
EN_cardError_t getCardExpiryDate(ST_cardData_t* cardData);
EN_cardError_t getCardPAN(ST_cardData_t* cardData);
#endif

//card.c
#include "card.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "STD_TYPES.h"

EN_cardError_t getCardHolderName(ST_cardData_t* cardData)
{
    uint8_t validity;
    printf("Please Enter The Card Holder Name (24 characters max - 20 characters min) : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(cardData->cardHolderName);
    //scanf("%[^\n]s", cardData->cardHolderName);
    if ((strlen(cardData->cardHolderName) <= 24) && (strlen(cardData->cardHolderName) >= 20))
    {
        return OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return WRONG_NAME;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "card.c"
```

It's probably a better idea to include the header file rather than the C file.

The latter will cause duplicate symbols if you link the `main` object file and the `card` object file since `main` includes the exact same code as `card` (as a subset).

Comment: it worked
when i used notepad++ and cmd it worked without errors , is there a difference between visual studio compiler and mingw ?

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim: if you compile and link just your main source file, what you have will work. It's bringing in both main and card to the linker which causes duplication. It's likely that the IDE will try to link both files together unless you specifically override. But that sort of defeats one of the main advantages of separate files since there's only one translation unit.

Comment: In other words, `gcc main.c` will work but not `gcc main.c card.c`.